# Grouping my data twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I use this code to group a number of time slot objects by staff name. So each staff member have a number of slots. The slots is currently with a 15 minutes interval.

```
IEnumerable<AvailabilityByStaffDto> groupedSlots =
            from slots in slotsAvailability
            group slots by slots.Staff.Name into g
            select new AvailabilityByStaffDto() 
                   { 
                       Name = g.Key, 
                       Slots = g.ToList() 
                   };
```

Is it possible to group these slots also by hour?
So that the **Slots** property might actually be **SlotHour** and within that we would have the **Slots**?

Edit:

OK, this is what I have now.

```
        IEnumerable<AvailabilityByStaffDto> groupedSlots =
            from slots in slotsAvailability
            group slots by slots.Staff.Name into g
            select new AvailabilityByStaffDto()
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Slots = (from b in g
                        group b by b.SlotStart.Hour into c
                        select new GroupedTimeslotDto()
                               {
                                   Hour = c.Key,
                                   QuarterSlots = c.ToList()
                               });
            };


public class AvailabilityByStaffDto
{
    public AvailabilityByStaffDto()
    {
        this.Slots = new List<DTO.GroupedTimeslotDto>();
    }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public List<DTO.GroupedTimeslotDto> Slots { get; set; }
}


public class GroupedTimeslotDto
{
    public GroupedTimeslotDto()
    {
        this.QuarterSlots = new List<DTO.TimeslotDto>();
    }

    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public List<DTO.TimeslotDto> QuarterSlots { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere the source type IEnumerable can't be converted to target type Generic.List. But I can't see why this is happening, I have only replicated the first grouping I had into a new level...

EDIT 2: Oh, ok. I think I forgot the last .ToList()

```
        IEnumerable<AvailabilityByStaffDto> groupedSlots =
            from slots in slotsAvailability
            group slots by slots.Staff.Name into g
            select new AvailabilityByStaffDto()
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Slots = (from b in g
                        group b by b.SlotStart.Hour into c
                        select new GroupedTimeslotDto()
                               {
                                   Hour = c.Key,
                                   QuarterSlots = c.ToList()
                               }).ToList()
            };
```

This might work.

Comment: yes, instead of ToList, do another groupby.

Comment: Do I need to create a strong type for that group?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to have the Slots property in a different way

Comment: Please also post the `Slot` type.

Comment: See my edit. I'm almost there, I think.